# WP7 Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to grab my files from isolated storage but unfortunatly it is pulling in all the files not just the specified ones from the pattern.

I'm using:

```
foreach (string fileName in storage.GetFileNames("*.item"))
```

Is this a known bug or am I just doing something wrong?

PS. The use of wildcards is **essential**

Any help very much apprieciated,

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it is not working. But you can try this one as well:

```
storage.GetFileNames().Select(fileName => fileName.EndsWith("item"));
```

Comment: This is a good solution I use something similar - hopefully this bug will be resolved - it was in the Beta and CTP, not sure why it was missed as it was pointed out to Microsoft, guess it was too late, maybe in Q1 2011 update it'll be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a IsolatedStorage search pattern bug in the final SDK release. Have a look at this post - http://blogs.compactframework.de/Peter.Nowak/2010/09/18/WP7+Final+SDK+Bug+IsolatedStorageFile+And+Ldquosearchpatternrdquo+And+A+Fix.aspx

HTH, indyfromoz

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. You'll need to either structure your files into folders if you want to limit what's retrieved or test/filter the filenames before loading them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in the CTP/Beta versions of IsolatedStorageFile.GetFileNames(string pattern)...

http://blogs.compactframework.de/Peter.Nowak/Trackback.aspx?guid=4d8d9b73-619f-43c7-bf6c-12429327206b

Answer (score 0):

This API bug has been fixed in the release of the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK (Otherwise known as the "Mango" release).

Your code will work fine now.